mod_cache appending "?" to all cache keys which results in cache MISSES
I've been tearing my hairs apart with this since yesterday, I'm trying to set up mod_cache to cache specific javascript files using the following configuration put in my virtual host configuration section:
<IfModule mod_cache.c>
                <IfModule mod_cache_disk.c>
                        CacheRoot /var/cache/apache24/mod_cache_disk
                        CacheQuickHandler off
                        CacheIgnoreQueryString On
                        <LocationMatch "chunk-.+\.js$">
                                CacheEnable disk                              
                                CacheHeader on
                                CacheDetailHeader on
                                CacheMaxFileSize 25000000
                                CacheDefaultExpire 86400
                        </LocationMatch>
                </IfModule>
        </IfModule>


The files are properly added to the cache  as shown by the headers of the http requests and the output of  htcacheclean -a -p /var/cache/apache24/mod_cache_disk/:
GET https://example.com/en/chunk-WXIYG2YB.js
HTTP/2 200 
last-modified: Sun, 01 Sep 2024 20:39:11 GMT
etag: "114a-62114d11a75eb-gzip"
accept-ranges: bytes
vary: Accept-Encoding
content-encoding: gzip
x-robots-tag: noindex
x-cache: MISS from mydomain.com
x-cache-detail: "cache miss: attempting entity save" from mydomain.com
content-type: application/javascript
date: Wed, 04 Sep 2024 10:35:43 GMT
server: Apache/2.4.59 (FreeBSD) OpenSSL/1.1.1t-freebsd
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2

and the cache:
https://example.com:443/en/chunk-IUI5V3WX.js?
https://example.com:443/en/chunk-IUI5V3WX.js?
https://example.com:443/en/chunk-WXIYG2YB.js?
https://example.com:443/en/chunk-WXIYG2YB.js?
...

As can be seen, in addition to the fact that there are duplicates, a "?" character is appended to the cache key which I suspect could lead to cache misses even though I have added the CacheIgnoreQueryString setting.
All requests that should hit the cache result in "cache miss: attempting entity save". I would really appreciate any help or idea at this point.
Thanks in advance

For some reason adding the configuration option CacheIgnoreCacheControl on seems to solve the issue: the cache is now hit, but I do not understand why this option is necessary since no headers preventing caching are sent. I am not a big fan of this solution, as it is more a workaround having the unfortunate side effect of making the Cache-Control header unusable.
Edit: Actually, after further investigations, it turned out that the problem was a rewrite rule that was conflicting the caching mecanism. The rule matched if a file wasn't found on disk, and therefore the cache was never hit.

First, read the docs for htcacheclean again. The ? is explained there.
To debug duplicate cache files: in addition to the response headers you pasted above, you also need to look at the request headers. Customise your access log to record cookies, for instance.
Another possible cause is CacheQuickHandler off.
When it comes to httpd, there’s really very few behaviours that can’t be explained after a careful reading of the docs to learn what each directive actually does.

Thanks for your help with this, it turned out the problem was a rewrite rule that was conflicting with caching, i edit my answer with details. Indeed, I am discovering that httpd is one of these pieces of software having a very comprehensive documentation that is always worth reading carefully in detail.
